# Proper PostgreSQL querying with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql

I'm using **node.js** server and **postgresSQL** DB trying create a reminder app. I am inserting data about reminders into database and then trying to check if the datetime is right to push reminder to user. my solution if datetime is correct:

[image: Here my solution]

**my question is: What is the proper way to check if the datetime is correct? maybe there is some kind of subsciption for that? or any other solutions for that?**

**Please help me out guys, thanks in advance, any help welcome!**

Comment: Pardon, but your question itself is an incomprehensible mess. You should rethink what and how are you asking, and avoid piling everything up into one.

Comment: @vitaly-t I edited the question. sorry for poor english skills, maybe now you will understand what I ment :) Thanks in advance Vitaly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right way to do, assuming you are using cronjobs.

You should check out Google's live database called Firebase.